# fetch specific string from data

Tags: regex, grep

i have some data

```
FON2_ORYSJ|FON2|FON4|LOC_Os11g38270|Os11g0595400
A1IGU8_ORYSJ|OsF5HL|Os06g0349700
A1IGU8_ORYSJ|OsF5HL|Os06g0349700
MTND1_ORYSJ|ARD1|SIP2|LOC_Os10g28350|Os10g0419400|OSJNBa0006I13.11
MTND1_ORYSJ|ARD1|SIP2|LOC_Os10g28350|Os10g0419400|OSJNBa0006I13.11
MTND1_ORYSJ|ARD1|SIP2|LOC_Os10g28350|Os10g0419400|OSJNBa0006I13.11
MTND1_ORYSJ|ARD1|SIP2|LOC_Os10g28350|Os10g0419400|OSJNBa0006I13.11
```

i need to fetch the LOC_OS* and Os* id separately.

the output should be like

```
LOC_Os11g38270
LOC_Os10g28350
LOC_Os10g28350
LOC_Os10g28350
LOC_Os10g28350
```

and

```
Os11g0595400
Os10g0419400
Os10g0419400
Os10g0419400
Os10g0419400
```

i tried to replace the | with \t and then use grep

grep -w 'LOC_Os*' test >go.txt

but not able to fetch those.

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following 2 commands:

```
cut -d'|' -f 4 test.dat | grep LOC_Os
```

and

```
cut -d'|' -f 5 test.dat | grep Os
```

**Explanation**: `cut` retrieves fields from the file, using pipe (|) as the delimited (`-d'|'`).  The first command returns field 4 (`-f 4`), and then greps within the result for `LOC_Os`.  The second command returns field 5 (`-f 5`) and then greps within the result for `Os`.